How effective have US sanctions been in detering or disrupting Pakistan's long range missile programs?
The United States recently imposed sanctions on Chinese companies supplying components for Pakistan's ballistic missile program, citing concerns over the proliferation of weapons of mass destruction:

United States Imposes Sanctions on Suppliers Contributing to Ballistic Missile Proliferation

How effective have US sanctions been in deterring or disrupting Pakistan's long range missile programs in the past two decades?

The Chinese suppliers of Iran get sanctioned too AFAICT https://www.scmp.com/news/china/article/3213011/us-sanctions-5-china-based-suppliers-iranian-company-selling-drones-russia ; https://www.timesofisrael.com/us-blacklists-iranian-chinese-companies-said-to-be-fronts-for-irgc-arms-purchases/ I'd wager a guess it hapens more often than with Pak-related companies.

Something specifically about raw material suppliers to Iran's program https://www.rferl.org/a/iran-chines-us-sanctiojn-missile-military-programs/32447336.html

It's probably best to delete your old Q and ask a new one, rather than try to massage it into a diff Q by changing 90% of its contents. You still have two rather diff Qs in the last two paras.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Why delete?  There is no answer yet, so changing the goalposts hardly matters.  Plus, in some ways/metrics StackExchange encourages edits to "problem questions".  Look for example at people that get frozen out of asking questions due to repeat low scores.  Meta tells them that deleting does not fix things.

As to one possible motivation for treating Pakistani nuclear endeavors with special concern, I could cite one Abdul Khan, physicist who did his bit for proliferation and got a pardon.

Well, before Biden it seems there were not much sanctions on the Pak missiles angle https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/9/15/will-us-sanctions-make-any-difference-to-pakistans-missiles-programme Perhaps too early to tell how effective they'd be long term. Especially if Trump comes back to the WH. Anyhow, Pakistan's government is defiant and says their program is far too advanced to be affected by the US.

I voted to reopen, but the problem is that--in my experience--reopening Qs like this doesn't work too well. You have enough rep to see the number of reopen you have.

Considering that Pakistan is currently an USA ally, probably not very well.
